# Arduino Matrix button box, one key press recognized as four keys pressed sametime

Tags: button, matrix, arduino

I'm trying to do matrix button box in this sample code with less buttons:

the code sketch and wiring scheme:

https://github.com/AM-STUDIO/32-FUNCTION-BUTTON-BOX

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsKhL.jpg

This is what i'm trying to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0cKQ.jpg

I've done this setup but when I press one key it recognized as four key pressed sametime. I think it's must be related rows and cols. I'm just a beginner in arduino world. I'll really appreciate if someone help.

I've tried changing rows and cols size in the code and changing rows and cols pins eachother but none of them is worked.

```
//BUTTON BOX 
//USE w ProMicro
//Tested in WIN10 + Assetto Corsa
//AMSTUDIO
//20.8.17

#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Joystick.h>

#define ENABLE_PULLUPS
#define NUMROTARIES 4
#define NUMBUTTONS 24
#define NUMROWS 5
#define NUMCOLS 5


byte buttons[NUMROWS][NUMCOLS] = {
  {0,1,2,3,4},
  {5,6,7,8,9},
  {10,11,12,13,14},
  {15,16,17,18,19},
  {20,21,22,23},
};

struct rotariesdef {
  byte pin1;
  byte pin2;
  int ccwchar;
  int cwchar;
  volatile unsigned char state;
};

rotariesdef rotaries[NUMROTARIES] {
  {0,1,24,25,0},
  {2,3,26,27,0},
  {4,5,28,29,0},
  {6,7,30,31,0},
};

#define DIR_CCW 0x10
#define DIR_CW 0x20
#define R_START 0x0

#ifdef HALF_STEP
#define R_CCW_BEGIN 0x1
#define R_CW_BEGIN 0x2
#define R_START_M 0x3
#define R_CW_BEGIN_M 0x4
#define R_CCW_BEGIN_M 0x5
const unsigned char ttable[6][4] = {
  // R_START (00)
  {R_START_M,            R_CW_BEGIN,     R_CCW_BEGIN,  R_START},
  // R_CCW_BEGIN
  {R_START_M | DIR_CCW, R_START,        R_CCW_BEGIN,  R_START},
  // R_CW_BEGIN
  {R_START_M | DIR_CW,  R_CW_BEGIN,     R_START,      R_START},
  // R_START_M (11)
  {R_START_M,            R_CCW_BEGIN_M,  R_CW_BEGIN_M, R_START},
  // R_CW_BEGIN_M
  {R_START_M,            R_START_M,      R_CW_BEGIN_M, R_START | DIR_CW},
  // R_CCW_BEGIN_M
  {R_START_M,            R_CCW_BEGIN_M,  R_START_M,    R_START | DIR_CCW},
};
#else
#define R_CW_FINAL 0x1
#define R_CW_BEGIN 0x2
#define R_CW_NEXT 0x3
#define R_CCW_BEGIN 0x4
#define R_CCW_FINAL 0x5
#define R_CCW_NEXT 0x6

const unsigned char ttable[7][4] = {
  // R_START
  {R_START,    R_CW_BEGIN,  R_CCW_BEGIN, R_START},
  // R_CW_FINAL
  {R_CW_NEXT,  R_START,     R_CW_FINAL,  R_START | DIR_CW},
  // R_CW_BEGIN
  {R_CW_NEXT,  R_CW_BEGIN,  R_START,     R_START},
  // R_CW_NEXT
  {R_CW_NEXT,  R_CW_BEGIN,  R_CW_FINAL,  R_START},
  // R_CCW_BEGIN
  {R_CCW_NEXT, R_START,     R_CCW_BEGIN, R_START},
  // R_CCW_FINAL
  {R_CCW_NEXT, R_CCW_FINAL, R_START,     R_START | DIR_CCW},
  // R_CCW_NEXT
  {R_CCW_NEXT, R_CCW_FINAL, R_CCW_BEGIN, R_START},
};
#endif

byte rowPins[NUMROWS] = {21,20,19,18,15}; 
byte colPins[NUMCOLS] = {14,16,10,9,8}; 

Keypad buttbx = Keypad( makeKeymap(buttons), rowPins, colPins, NUMROWS, NUMCOLS); 

Joystick_ Joystick(JOYSTICK_DEFAULT_REPORT_ID, 
  JOYSTICK_TYPE_JOYSTICK, 32, 0,
  false, false, false, false, false, false,
  false, false, false, false, false);

void setup() {
  Joystick.begin();
  rotary_init();}

void loop() { 

  CheckAllEncoders();

  CheckAllButtons();

}

void CheckAllButtons(void) {
      if (buttbx.getKeys())
    {
       for (int i=0; i<LIST_MAX; i++)   
        {
           if ( buttbx.key[i].stateChanged )   
            {
            switch (buttbx.key[i].kstate) {  
                    case PRESSED:
                    case HOLD:
                              Joystick.setButton(buttbx.key[i].kchar, 1);
                              break;
                    case RELEASED:
                    case IDLE:
                              Joystick.setButton(buttbx.key[i].kchar, 0);
                              break;
            }
           }   
         }
     }
}


void rotary_init() {
  for (int i=0;i<NUMROTARIES;i++) {
    pinMode(rotaries[i].pin1, INPUT);
    pinMode(rotaries[i].pin2, INPUT);
    #ifdef ENABLE_PULLUPS
      digitalWrite(rotaries[i].pin1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(rotaries[i].pin2, HIGH);
    #endif
  }
}


unsigned char rotary_process(int _i) {
   unsigned char pinstate = (digitalRead(rotaries[_i].pin2) << 1) | digitalRead(rotaries[_i].pin1);
  rotaries[_i].state = ttable[rotaries[_i].state & 0xf][pinstate];
  return (rotaries[_i].state & 0x30);
}

void CheckAllEncoders(void) {
  for (int i=0;i<NUMROTARIES;i++) {
    unsigned char result = rotary_process(i);
    if (result == DIR_CCW) {
      Joystick.setButton(rotaries[i].ccwchar, 1); delay(50); Joystick.setButton(rotaries[i].ccwchar, 0);
    };
    if (result == DIR_CW) {
      Joystick.setButton(rotaries[i].cwchar, 1); delay(50); Joystick.setButton(rotaries[i].cwchar, 0);
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: could you paste your code here instead of linking github/images?

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart  sorry for that, I've added the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the code you actually used instead of the code from another project that yours is based upon? That way we can analyse what your code does. Else we will suggest things you may have already tried.

That said, did you modify the setup to this?

```
#define NUMBUTTONS 18
#define NUMROWS 4
#define NUMCOLS 5


byte buttons[NUMROWS][NUMCOLS] = {
  {0,1,2,3,4},
  {5,6,7,8,9},
  {10,11,12,13,14},
  {15,16,17}
};
```

You also need to make sure these line up with your wiring:

```
byte rowPins[NUMROWS] = {21,20,19,18,15}; 
byte colPins[NUMCOLS] = {14,16,10,9,8};
```

If that doesn't solve it, are the 'pressed' buttons in a column or a row?